# Is stateless session thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, nhibernate, session, thread-safety, stateless-session

I know ISession is not thread safe. Is IStatelssSession also not thread safe? I guess the answer is no. I did a quick search but didn't find a reference for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please stop adding "Thanks" to all your answers. Thank people by upvoting good questions and answers when you come across them, but *stop adding "thanks"*. Also, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: "Thanks" is considered part of a tagline/signature, and there are numerous posts on meta about this not being allowed. If the previous link didn't do it for you, here's another one - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81978/automatic-signature - or this one - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38570/is-adding-a-signature-considered-spamming

Comment: Please don't use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already "signed" with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: "Thanks" is considered as such. There really isn't more to say on this issue.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Thanks for freezing my account. (I have wrote an email to stackexchange team asking them to delete all of my accounts, so this is my last comment on your site)

Comment: According to what I can see your suspension is lifted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The StatelessSessionImpl holds a ConnectionManager which holds an IDbConnection - SqlConnection is not thread-safe, so that would be no.

Although the NH trunk code documentation does not specific whether or not it is.

Edit: The code also shows no thread synchronization and it also holds an ITransaction.